# Warn User When Navigating from Page with Unsaved Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an ASP.NET website and I want to implement logic to warn the user when they are navigating away from a page they've edited.

I found quite a bit of info on the web, although most of it seems quite outdated. Note that I still have a lot to learn about jQuery.

The following code displays the message as expected.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

However, the following code--which is supposed to be equal to the code above only when a change is made--does not work. No warning is ever displayed.

```
$('input').change(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Your changes have not been saved?" };
});
```

Can someone say why the second snippet doesn't work? Or perhaps you can point me to a reference that is more recent.

Comment: When are you executing `$('input').change(function...`? Is it in a `$(document).ready` or similar handler?

Comment: I just have it in a `<script>` block at the top of my page. This is the same place the first snippet is, which works. Like I said, I'm still learning jQuery, but doesn't the second snippet cause the function to run when any of the input elements fire a change event?

Comment: That will add/replace the listener every time a change event on an input fires, you should only add it once. An alternative is to use *onbeforeunload* to see if any form control's *value* is different to its *defaultValue* and warn if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input elements probably do not exist when the code is executed. Try using the [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to detect changes on all input elements, or wrap your code in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

Example:

```
$('input').live("change", function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Your changes have not been saved?" };
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input').change(function () {
      window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Your changes have not been saved?" };
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I used `$(document).ready()` and it appears to be working. I'll learn about `.live`. Thanks!