# Preventing users from accidentally navigating away from unsaved pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pjax

I got the snippet below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825097/warn-user-when-navigating-from-page-with-unsaved-changes) SO post, and it works when a user tries to reload the page or close the browser etc. but if the user clicks on a link then it lets them naivagate away, and then incorrectly starts displaying the message on the wrong page. I am using pjax for the links.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('textarea').change(function () {
          window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Your changes to the survey have not been saved?" };
      });
    });
```

Comment: The page never really gets the status `unload` so you need to trigger that when you click a link.

Comment: Can you give a code sample please?

Comment: @lee code sample to trigger specific event? There are thousand of 'code sample' like this, try yourself to search, you should find it...

Comment: Make a function that calls the `window.onbeforeunload` and bind it to your links.

Comment: @roasted you are assuming that I read putvande's answer AND have the necessary background knowledge to interpret it to 'I need to trigger a specific event', when I may have interpreted is as 'huh what?'

Comment: $('a').click(function(){
          window.onbeforeunload();
        }); does not work...

Comment: You probably want to be using trigger: $('a').click(function(){
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');
});

Comment: @BenWells that does not work either...

Answer (score 8):

You should use `onbeforeunload` like this, inconditionally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
saved=true; // initially, it is saved (no action has been done)

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    if (!saved) {
        return "You did not save, do you want to do it now?";
    }
}
</script>
```

It is not safe to handle this event only when another event is fired. The `onchange` event of your textarea here probably don't fire before you click on a link so the window won't handle the `onbeforeunload` at all. The link will work as expected: you will get redirected.

To deal with the `saved` flag, you could listen to what happens in your textarea, for example, when the user is actually typing something:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    saved=false;
});
```

Then, if you save the data in ajax, the save button could set it back to true:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
    // ajax save
    saved=true;
});
```

Otherwise, it will load the next page with the `saved` flag on.

Comment: He is using onbeforenload, he is saying that when you click on link, onbeforeunload is not called

Comment: @mara-mfa I just noticed that, thanks. I updated to explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @Frederik.L when I click on a link, onbeforeunload is still not getting called

Comment: Where is the onbeforeunload defined ?

Answer (score 3):

what about something like the following? 
Listening on all `<a>` links and then, depending on whether the variable needToSave is set to true, showing the message or letting it go.

```
var needToSave = false; // Set this to true on some change
// listen on all <a ...> clicks
$(document).click("a", function(event){        
    if (needToSave == true) {
        alert("You need to save first");
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** (as per Roasted's suggestion) this should trigger the unload event every time the link is clicked and perform your existing logic:

```
// listen on all <a ...> clicks
$(document).click("a", function(event){        
   $(window).trigger("unload");
});
```

jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/k2fYM/

Comment: This looks legit, but I am still waiting to see if there is a "built in" solution before marking this as the answer.

Comment: Not sure if there is anything built in (or what you mean by that). Nevertheless, see the update what roasted meant by triggering an unload event.

Comment: it does - added jsFiddle

Comment: Clearly your solution does work, but just not for me for some reason :(

Comment: If you manage to put that in jsFiddle, I am sure we will find out

Comment: The problem is that I am using Rails so there are a lots of little pieces that may be interfering that cannot be put on the fiddle

Comment: I used the first example but needed to add `event.stopPropagation()` *before* the return as my scenario was in an ajax environment and clicking on `a` links was also bound to other handlers.  So what was happening is that the alert was firing but then the other page was loading anyway.  Adding `event.stopPropagation()` stopped that.